# Reading and write strings in binary files c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode-string, wstring

I'm trying to develop a small *Windows* application to improve my C++ skill outside MFC framework and to help my studies about foreign languages.
I would like to make a small, personal and easy-to-port_and_use dictionary and, while I have no problems in developing the GUI, I'm having real pain in saving and restoring data.
My idea is to write down a binary files structured as follow:

```
int (representing the number of words)
int (representing the string length + \0)
sequence of characters zero-terminated.
```

Now, I'm learning russian and my primary language is italian, so I can't use plain old std::string to write down words, moreover, thank you Microsoft, I'm using VS2010 with all the goods and [bads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950718/wrote-to-a-file-using-stdwofstream-the-file-remained-empty) that come with it. I'm showing you my routines to write down int and wstring:

```
//Writing int
void CDizionario::ScriviInt( int nInt, wofstream& file ) const
{
    file.write( reinterpret_cast < const wchar_t * > ( &nInt ), sizeof( nInt ) );
    file.flush();
}
// Writing string
void CDizionario::ScriviWString( int nLStringa, const wstring* pStrStringa, wofstream& file ) const
{
    wchar_t cTerminatore;
    string strStringa;
    file.write( pStrStringa->c_str(), nLStringa );
    file.flush();
    cTerminatore = L'\0';
    file.write( &cTerminatore, sizeof( wchar_t ) );
    file.flush();
}
// Reading int
void CDizionario::LeggiInt( int *pInt, wifstream& file )
{
    file.read( reinterpret_cast < wchar_t * >( pInt ), sizeof( int ) );
}
// Reading wstring
void CDizionario::LeggiWString( int nLStringa, wstring& strStringa, wifstream& file )
{
    wchar_t *pBuf;
    streamsize byteDaLeggere;
    byteDaLeggere = nLStringa;
    pBuf = new wchar_t[(unsigned int)( byteDaLeggere * sizeof( wchar_t ) )];
    file.read( pBuf, byteDaLeggere * sizeof( wchar_t ) );
    strStringa.append( pBuf );
    delete [] pBuf;
}
// Constructor
CDizionario::CDizionario( void )
{
    m_pLoc = new locale( locale::classic(), new codecvt_utf8_utf16 );
}
// Somewhere in my code before calling LeggiInt/ScriviInt/LeggiWString/ScriviWString:
// ...
file.imbue( *m_pLoc );
```

Well, my first test has been: *ciao - привет*, result:

```
01 00 ee bc 90 22 05 00 ee bc 90 22 63 69 61 6f
00 ec b3 8c 07 00 ee bc 90 22 d0 bf d1 80 d0 b8
d0 b2 d0 b5 d1 82 00 ec b3 8c
```

Numbers are read correctly, the problem comes when I write down strings: I'd expect that *ciao* (63 69 61 6f 00 ec b3 8c) was written in 10 bytes (wchar_t size) and not in 5, as happens for russian translation ( d0 bf d1 80 d0 b8 d0 b2 d0 b5 d1 82 00 ec b3 8c).
Obviously I'm missing something, but I can't figure what it is. Can you guys help me out? Also, if you know a better approach to solve the problem, I'm open minded.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**
Following the first of the two method presented by @JamesKanze, I've decided to sacrify some portability and let the system do my homework:
`void CDizionario::LeggiInt( int *pInt, ifstream& file )
{
    file.read( reinterpret_cast( pInt ), sizeof( int ) );
}`

void CDizionario::LeggiWString( int nLStringa, wstring& strStringa, ifstream& file )
{
    char *pBuf;
    streamsize byteDaLeggere;
    wstring_convert> converter;
    byteDaLeggere = nLStringa;
    pBuf = new char[byteDaLeggere];
    file.read( pBuf, byteDaLeggere );
    strStringa = converter.from_bytes( pBuf );
    delete [] pBuf;
}

void CDizionario::ScriviInt( int nInt, ofstream& file ) const
{
    file.write( reinterpret_cast( &nInt ), sizeof( nInt ) );
    file.flush();
}
void CDizionario::ScriviWString( const wstring* pStrStringa, ofstream& file ) const
{
    char cTerminatore;
    string strStringa;
    wstring_convert> converter;
    strStringa = converter.to_bytes( pStrStringa->c_str() );
    ScriviInt( strStringa.length() + 1, file );
    file.write( strStringa.c_str(), strStringa.length() );
    file.flush();
    cTerminatore = '\0';
    file.write( &cTerminatore, sizeof( char ) );
    file.flush();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not sufficiently specified the format of the binary file.
How do you represent an `int` (how many bytes, big-endian or
little-endian), nor the encoding and the format of the
characters.  The classical network representation would be
a big-endian four byte (unsigned) integer, and UTF-8.  Since
this is something you're doing for your self, you can (and
probably should) simplify, using little-endian for integer, and
UTF-16LE; these formats correspond to the internal format *under
Windows*.  (Note that such code will not be portable, not even
to Apple or Linux on the same architecture, and the there is
a small chance that the data become unreadable on a new system.)
This is basically what you seem to be attempting, but...

You're trying to write raw binary.  The only standard way to do
this would be to use `std::ofstream` (and `std::ifstream` to
read), with the file opened in binary mode *and* imbued with the
`"C"` locale.  For anything else, there will (or may) be some
sort of code translation and mapping in the `std::filebuf`.
Given this (and the fact that this way of writing data is not
portable to any other system), you may want to just use the
system level functions: `CreateFile` to open, `WriteFile` and
`ReadFile` to write and read, and `CloseHandle` to close.  (See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to be portable, on the other hand, I would recommend
using the standard network format for the data.  Format it into
a buffer (`std::vector<char>`), and write that; at the other
end, read into a buffer, and parse that.  The read and write
routines for an integer (actually an unsigned integer) might be
something like:

```
void
writeUnsignedInt( std::vector<char>& buffer, unsigned int i )
{
    buffer.push_back( (i >> 24) & oxFF );
    buffer.push_back( (i >> 16) & oxFF );
    buffer.push_back( (i >>  8) & oxFF );
    buffer.push_back( (i      ) & oxFF );
}

unsigned int
readUnsignedInt( 
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator& current,
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator end )
{
    unsigned int retval = 0;
    int shift = 32;
    while ( shift != 0 && current != end ) {
        shift -= 8;
        retval |= static_cast<unsigned char>( *current ) << shift;
        ++ current;
    }
    if ( shift != 0 ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Unexpected end of file" );
    }
    return retval;
}
```

For the characters, you'll have to convert your std::wstring to
std::string in UTF-8, using one of the many conversion routines
available on the network.  (The problem is that the encoding of
`std::wstring`, nor even the size of a `wchar_t`, is not
standardized.  Of the systems I'm familiarized, Windows and AIX
use UTF-16, most others UTF-32; in both cases with the byte
order dependent on the platform.  This makes portable code a bit
more difficult.)

Globally, I find it easier to just do everything directly in
UTF-8, using `char`.  This won't work with the Windows
interface, however.

And finally, you don't need the trailing `'\0'` if you output
the length.

Comment: Well, reading this and given the fact that I'm developing a MFC GUI, I guess that porting should not be of interest for now. I'll check your first hint.

Comment: What about using a small dbms like sqlite, leaving to it the dirt job?

Comment: Following your first hints, I let the system decide how the bytes have to be converted. I'll update the question with solution for those who are interested.

Answer (score 0):

@IssamTP, привет

As mentioned by @James Kanze, working with foreign non-latin languages inevitably pushes you to per-byte format conventions and locales. So it may be worth to not re-invent the wheel and use existing technologies like XML (so the technology will serve the nuances and encode/decode non-latin chars properly).

Comment: привет @YuriSchkatula, do you have a link to one of these libs at hand?

Comment: This is definitely the solution I would recommend in a production environment, where portability is important, and the data structures are complex and evoluative.  For what he's trying to do, they may be overkill, however: interfacing to Xerces, for example, will entail more work that what he needs to implement the little bit he needs by hand.

Comment: @IssamTP, you can count on MS XML http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988 or Xerces or TinyXML, for example. There are various libs so it may be worth for future experience at least to try them.

Comment: @YurySchkatula большое спасибо. Thank you very much, I'll check on these stuffs.