# Write current username to file in windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am attempting to create a program which writes the current username in text form (example **John**) to file on windows. I tried it through `GetUserNameEx(NameDisplay, name, &size);` but the output value is

> 002CF514

I tried this:

```
#ifndef _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <Security.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    TCHAR name[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

    GetUserNameEx(NameDisplay, name, &size);

    ofstream File;
    File.open("NAME.TXT", ios::app);
    File << name;
    File.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `NameDisplay` is a wide string, you have to use `wofstream` instead of `ofstream`. Also do not use `TCHAR` it is [awfully deprecated thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant). Use `wchar_t` instead. So correct version should be:

```
#ifndef _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <Security.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t name[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

    GetUserNameEx(NameDisplay, name, &size);

    std::locale::global(std::locale("Russian_Russia"));
    wofstream File;
    File.open("NAME.TXT", ios::app);
    File << name;
    File.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** Apparently Visual Studio always uses ANSI encoding to write a streams, so you have to imbue a locale to the `fstream`. Updated version of the code prints my user name in the Cyrillic locale correctly. You would have to change locale name for your country/language. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950718/wrote-to-a-file-using-stdwofstream-the-file-remained-empty) answer for the additional info.

Comment: *Also do not use TCHAR it is awfully deprecated thing.* [Really?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/234365/464709) Since when?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Since Windows 98 era actually.

Comment: Sorry, that's complete nonsense. `TCHAR` has never been deprecated, and I've personally been using it far later than Windows 98 (and I'm not alone). The question I linked to in my previous comment also (partially) disagrees with you.

Comment: Why was this solution downvoted? It solves the problem. The OP's question explicitly defines UNICODE.

Comment: @Marek Updated my answer.

Comment: @Ari0nhh with this code I again get output 0022FB1C but I need him in text form example: John

Comment: You need `pubsetbuf` for this to work. Also use Unicode filename instead of ANSI. Use this instead: `wofstream File; wchar_t buf[128]; File.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, 128); File.open(L"NAME.TXT", ios::app);`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: if you look at the voting on that question, I think you'll see a clear majority against using continuing to use TCHAR.  There's just no point any more, and it is dangerous, because it (typically) means that you don't get an error from the compiler if you accidentally try to build for ANSI, the program just doesn't work properly.  YMMV.